# Kibana Monitoring tab - Cant see all Logstash Nodes

Tags: logstash, kibana

I have 3 Logstash servers with the following configured in their logstash.yml file:

> xpack.management.enabled: true xpack.monitoring.enabled: true
>   xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.username: logstash_system
>   xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.password: pass
>   xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.hosts:
>   ["http://es1.:9200","http://es2.:9200","http://es3.:9200"]
>   xpack.management.pipeline.id: ["Firewall", "HSM","NX","ESET"]
>   xpack.management.elasticsearch.hosts:
>   ["http://es1:9200","http://es2.:9200","http://es3.:9200"]
>   xpack.management.elasticsearch.username: logstash_admin
>   xpack.management.elasticsearch.password: pass

However, I only keep seeing 1 of them under the Monitoring - Nodes tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elastic's support eventually helped me find the cause.
As I duplicated the servers they had the same cluster uuid.
You can find out what's your UUID by running

> cat /usr/share/logstash/data/uuid

Unfortunately the only way to solve uuid duplication issues is by re-installing Logstash from scratch. And I mean entirely, wiping out everything. 
After doing so I can now see all hosts in Kibana.

Answer (score 1):

Do they have different `node.name` ?
If so, what do you see in the other logstash's nodes logs ?

Comment: Different names of course. However, it's altering between them in the nodes tab. Sometimes one, sometimes the other and sometimes the third one.